Test doubles in Instrumented End-To-End tests
I have a Fragment screen which launches a WebView using a registerActivityForResult and I want to have an End-to-End Instrumented test which has this Fragment in the flow.
class OAuthLoginScreen(
    registry: ActivityResultRegistry? = null,
    private val loginToOldPlatformUseCase: AccountsApiLoginToOldPlatformUseCase
    = DefaultAccountsApiLoginToOldPlatformUseCase(),
) : Fragment(), Screen {

    private val loginLauncher = registry?.let {
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), it) { result ->
            val data = result.data
            if (result.resultCode == ComponentActivity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                setAuthStateFromResult(data)
            } else {
                activity?.finish()
            }
        }
    } ?: registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        val data = result.data
        if (result.resultCode == ComponentActivity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            setAuthStateFromResult(data)
        } else {
            activity?.finish()
        }
    }
...

What I am able to do right now:

JVM Unit test using mockk, test doubles and test registry ✅
Instrumented End-to-End test with previous Activity using real requests and UI Automator ✅

What I am unable to do:

Instrumented End-to-End test with previous Activity using test doubles, test registry for OAuthLoginScreen  ❌

Is it even possible? I want to launch this Fragment from my previous Activity but have test doubles and not launch my WebView at all. I understand this is possible with launchInContainer() as I already did in case 1 but how can I implement something similar when multiple screens and navigations are involved?
